# My OpenGL ES renderBuffer doesn't display anything

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, render

First of all sorry for my broken english, I'n not native and should have worked more at school :S

Those days I'm trying to build an AR system using OpengL ES on iOS.

I retrieve camera frames using AVCaptureSession and sent then both to a tracking algorithm and my OpenGL ES display class (which wait for the rotation and translation from the tracking algorithm). In the meantime I'm reading a video to display on an OpenGL plane placed at the same position as a real plane is the scene (I don't know if I am clear).

My goal is to use only one VBO and one shader to render the whole thing (image taken from camera in the background and plan with a video texture positioned using the rotation and translation given by my tracking algorithm).

I don't know why but nothing is displayed, here is the render code (called each frame) :

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

[self setProjectionMatrix];

glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionUniform, 1, 0, projection.glMatrix);

//Wait for rotation and translation
@synchronized(self.trackeriOS){

    transfo = [trackeriOS getMat];
}

[self dumpMatrix:transfo];

[self fillModelViewMatrix:transfo];

glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, finalModelView);

videoTexture = [self setupTextureFromBuffer:self.buffer];

if (videoTexture == -1) {
    NSLog(@"swap");
}
  if (cameraVideoTexture == -1) {
    NSLog(@"swap");
}

else {

    glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)        (sizeof(float) * 3));

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, videoTexture);
    glUniform1i(_textureUniform, 0);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionUniform, 1, 0, modelViewIdentity);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelViewIdentity);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cameraVideoTexture);
    glUniform1i(_cameraVideotextureUniform, 1);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

    CVBufferRelease(self.buffer);

    glDeleteTextures(1, &cameraVideoTexture);
    glDeleteTextures(1,&videoTexture);

}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Edit 2: This is how I create my OpenGL texture from an CVImageBufferRef given by the AVFoundation delegate function while reading camera video datas:

```
- (void)processNewCameraFrame:(CVImageBufferRef)cameraFrame;
{
    dispatch_async(backgroundImageDisplay, ^(void) {
    self.cameraVideoBuffer = cameraFrame;
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
    int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame);
    int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame);

    glGenTextures(1, &cameraVideoTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cameraVideoTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA,  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame));

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);

    CMTime outputItemTime = [videoOutput itemTimeForHostTime:CACurrentMediaTime()];
    if ([[self videoOutput] hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:outputItemTime2]) {
        self.buffer = [[self videoOutput] copyPixelBufferForItemTime:outputItemTime2  itemTimeForDisplay:NULL];

        //The above render function
        [self render];
    }

    });

}
```

Edit : I forgot to say I set my VBO like this :

```
- (void)setupVBOs {

glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

NSLog(@"OpenGL View, set up VBO 1");

}
```

And I set up the entry point to my shader like this :

```
-(void)setTextureProgramShader {

_positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle1, "Position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot);

_projectionUniform = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle1, "Projection");
_modelViewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle1, "Modelview");

_texCoordSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle1, "TexCoordIn");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_texCoordSlot);

_textureUniform = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle1, "Texture");


}
```

Finally the vertex shader is :

```
attribute vec4 Position; // 1

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

attribute vec2 TexCoordIn; 

varying vec2 TexCoordOut;


void main(void) { // 4

gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position; // 6
TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
```

Comment: The first thing to try is setting the clear color to something else (Red) and see if that works: glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1).  Do you get any errors?  It will be easier to find a good OpenGL ES 2.0 sample that already works and modify that.

Comment: I tried to modify those values, nothing seem to happen, you're right I 'm gonna try doing an easier program, it may have been a problem in the creation of the openGL texture (I will edit my post and post this part of the code too). Thanks for your answer

Comment: Ok I found my problem : I am stupid, I needed to display the OpenGL content on the main Thread ...

Comment: All of the OpenGL ES calls must execute from the same thread.  This article details:http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1